# Import Tensorflow in Python module called from MATLAB

Tags: python, linux, matlab, tensorflow, anaconda

here is the setting and what I'm trying to do.

SETTING

1. Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS
2. MATLAB R2016a
3. Anaconda 4.1.1 (Python 2.7 version)
4. Tensorflow r0.10 (GPU enabled) in Conda virtual environment called TF

Tensorflow works fine when called directly from Python. My problem is to call a Python module that uses Tensorflow from MATLAB.

Using `pyversion` I changed the executable file used by MATLAB as a Python interpreter. It points to `/anaconda2/envs/TF/bin/python`. To check proper execution, I created the following python module:

```
#myMod
def Foo(n):
    return n
```

From MATLAB command line, `py.myMod.Foo(n)` works fine.
Now I modify the module to import tensorflow:

```
#myMod2
import tensorflow as tf

def Foo(n):
    return n
```

From MATLAB command line, `py.myMod2.Foo(n)` blocks MATLAB. I see the *Busy* signal on the lower left corner of the MATLAB window. That's it, as if it got stuck in an infinite loop.

Finally, please note that:

1. Other import statements work fine. For instance replacing `import tensorflow as tf` with `import numpy as np` and typing `py.myMod2.Foo(n)` works.
2. I succeeded in the following partial solution (after replacing `libstdc++.so.6` and `libstdc++.so.6.0.17` found in the MATLAB directory with the ones in found the TF environment):

   ```
   #myScript
   import myMod2 as m

   n = 5
   result = m.Foo(n)
   ```

Now, from MATLAB prompt:

```
name = 'myScript.py';
cmd = ['source activate TF; python ', cd, '/', name, '; source deactivate'];
[status, commandOut] = unix(cmd);
```

This solution is only a workaround as it delegates UNIX to do the job. Moreover, it completely misses variable passing between MATLAB and Python.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EC

Comment: did you find solution for this problem, coz I have the same problem